# Android Layout - ScrollView blank space and in front of menus

Tags: android, android-layout

Its my first question here.
I want the main page to have a scrollview with an image on top and some text on the botton of the imagem.
Created the scrollview on other activity and included on the app.bar.main activity.
Now I have 2 problems.
1 there is a blank space on top of the imageview inside the scrollview.
2 the scrollview gets in front of the toolbar, not letting me press the icons.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/logoprefeitura"

            />

    </ScrollView>



</RelativeLayout>
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <include layout="@layout/content_main" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />




    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end" android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera"
        app:backgroundTint="#06568a" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Try replacing the scrollview and relativelayout in your xml code. Make scrollview the parent view and the rest in its child.

Comment: make a new xml with all my stuff and include it inside de scrollview?

Comment: your original xml looks fine just replace scrollview tag with relativelayout tag and also change the width and height to match_parent

Answer (score 0):

Use NestedScrollView instead of ScrollView.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/logoprefeitura"/>


</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: [link]http://s30.postimg.org/80n28pge9/problema.png still getting the same blank space. also the top margin ending on top of the menu buttons.

Comment: @RicardoCaldas I think, your Image causes this problem. Try to replace your imageView with a long Textview for experimenting. See if there will be a blank at the top again. Also you have android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" at your RelativeLayout. Remove it and try again.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:src="@drawable/slice11pp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
```

found the answer. was the scale of the image inside de image view.